# BS4 scrape everything bar <h2> tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am currently writing a scraper am stuck on the last little bit which ironically looks like it should be the easiest. The html is a little pop up and contains the following code structure.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Website Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>Full Development Description</h2><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="saaa" value="000" />
        <input type="hidden" name="saaa" value="000" />

        This is the text I would like to to extract                  

        <input type="hidden" name="saa" value="This is the text 
                       I would like to to extract" size="7" />

        <input type="hidden" name="saaa" value="000" />
        <input type="hidden" name="saa" value="000" />

     </body>
</html>
```

I am looking to extract the This is the text I would like to to extract part. This part is written twice, once as just plain text in the body and once as the value as a hidden input. There is no way to identify this hidden input from the other hidden input so the easiest way I think will be to extract the text.

My plan is to extract the body which I know how to do. But I don't know how to 'exclude' tags allowing me to remove the h2 tags and input tags and all data with in these tags.

I extract the body using the following code:

```
 body = response.css('body').extract()
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @A.Kot I have added the code but its just `body = response.css('body').extract()` I don't know how to remove html code from the bs object.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it for you, assuming that only the input field you want is of size 7.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> page = open('temp.htm').read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
>>> theInput = soup.findAll('input', attrs={'type': 'hidden', 'name': 'saa', 'size': '7'})
>>> len(theInput)
1
>>> theInput[0].attrs
{'type': 'hidden', 'size': '7', 'value': 'This is the text \n                       I would like to to extract', 'name': 'saa'}
```